# Jquery mask плохо работает на мобильном ios

Tags: jquery

Пишу на yii2, отключил все сторонние скрипты, оставил только jquery and jquery mask по cdn и файл с такими кодом

```
$('input[type="tel"]').mask('+7 (999) 999 99-99');
```

На андройд и пк всё работает, а вот на мобилки ios при вводе в input клавиатура подвисает и цифры отображаются с задержкой.
Как исправить?

Answer (score -1):

В общем проблема была не в mask а в css. На ios при абсолютных after before выходящих за пределы родительского элемента с overflow: hidden всё лагает.

По мне причина одна - IOS фигня.

Перестаньте покупать этот хлам.